# How to do looping to rename and read a file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have many files in a folder with the same extension file. I want to rename the file one by one then do the other process, which is `Proc_After_Rename`. In this process, I will read some information of the file. In this process, I want to read the information of the file one by one based on the previous process to rename the extension file name. After I finish do the process, then I pick again the file to rename and do the process.
For now, I can rename the file, but it rename it all the files directly before I do the other process. ANf when I go to this process `Proc_After_Rename`, I read the information for all the file, because all the file already rename the extension. Anyone can help, please

### UPDATED

```
Function Proc_After_Rename
{
$Path = "C:\Users\SS\PowerShell\"
Write-Host "Do some process with .pro file"
$Job_Info =  Get-ChildItem -Path "$store\*.ini" -File -Force
& $Path\UIni.exe $Job_Info AGM CRM AGM_CUR_CRM AGM_CUR_CRM.CMD #this how I read the .ini file
start-sleep -s 1

$Read_AGM_CUR_CRM = Get-Content .\AGM_CUR_CRM.CMD
$a_AGM_CUR_CRM,$b_AGM_CUR_CRM     = $Read_AGM_CUR_CRM -split "="
$b_AGM_CUR_CRM 
Pick_file

}

Function Pick_file
{
$WKFD= "C:\Users\SS\PowerShell\"
$store = "$WKFD\GM"
$files = @(Get-ChildItem -Path "$store\*.txt") 
Foreach ($file in $files)
{
    # Check file existence
    if (Test-Path -Path $file -PathType Leaf)
    {
        # Get file name from object path file $file
        $file_name = @(Get-ChildItem -Path "$file" -Name)
        # Replace the .cue with .pro
        $new_name = $file_name -replace ".txt", ".ini" 
        # Rename the file
        Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName "$new_name"
      
    }
Proc_After_Rename

}
}

$A = Pick_file
```

Comment: What is that 'process' and why is this a problem ?

Comment: you are already processing your files one by one with that 'foreach'

Comment: I updated my script to explain what is the process after rename it. @D.J.

Comment: "I want to rename the file one by one and then do the other process".  This is very unclear, and your examples do not clarify.  How many files should the other process work on?  One file each time it is invoked?  All the .ini files that are now available?  Clarify your intent in order to get useful answers.

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks @WalterMitty

Comment: The new code you show is very contradictory to what you ask in the question. The function `Proc_After_Rename is called` where it does stuff actually _BEFORE_ the rename in function `Pick_file` is called. Really confusing..

Answer (score 3):

With the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet, you can iterate the results easily by directly piping them through to a `Foreach-Object`. Inside that loop, every file found is a [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8#properties) object, represented by the automatic variable `$_`.
Using the `-Filter` parameter the below code gets only files with a *.txt extension and by adding the `-File` switch you only recieve FileInfo objects, not Directory objects.

If I understand the question correctly, you want to first rename each *.txt file to *.ini and then do some more stuff with the renamed file. This should do it:

```
$store = "C:\Users\HH"

Get-ChildItem -Path $store -Filter '*.txt' -File | ForEach-Object {
    # the automatic variable '$_' here represents a single FileInfo object in the list.
    # you don't need to test if the file exists, if it doesn't, Get-ChildItem would not return it.

    # create the new name for the file. Simply change the extension to '.ini'
    $newName = '{0}.ini' -f $_.BaseName
    # rename the file and get a reference to it using the -PassThru parameter
    $renamedFile = $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -PassThru

    # for testing/proof:
    # remember that the '$_' variable now has old file name info.
    Write-Host ("File '{0}' is now renamed to '{1}'" -f $_.FullName, $renamedFile.FullName)

    # now do the rest of your processing, using the $renamedFile FileInfo object.
    # you can see what properties and methods a FileInfo object has here:
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8#properties
    # to get the full path and filename for instance, use $renamedFile.FullName

    # ........ #
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. But it also renames all the file one time. it does not what I expect for :(. @Theo

Comment: This answer is coded better than my answer,  which used most of the OP's code.  The reason the OP still got unexpected results is that the code the OP plugged into the "rest of the processing" probably replicated a bug in the original effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
    # Rename the file
    Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName "$new_name"

    # path of the renamed file
    $new_path_file = "$store\$new_name"

    # This is the process after rename the file
    # ........ #
   #Put your process here and make sure you reference the new file, as long as its in 
   #the foreach you are good. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is the Get-ChildItem inside Proc_After_Rename.  This presents UIni with a list of files instead of a file.  I have tried to fix this problem by reworking your code, and sliding part of Proc_After_Rename into Pick_File.  I haven't tested any of this,  but I hope it gives you a better idea of how to organize your code.

If I were writing this from scratch, I would use pipelines.

```
Function Pick_file
{
$WKFD= "C:\Users\SS\PowerShell\"
$store = "$WKFD\GM"
$files = @(Get-ChildItem -Path "$store\*.txt") 
Foreach ($file in $files)
{
    # Check file existence
    if (Test-Path -Path $file -PathType Leaf)
    {
        # Get file name from object path file $file
        $file_name = @(Get-ChildItem -Path "$file" -Name)
        # Replace the .cue with .pro
        $new_name = $file_name -replace ".txt", ".ini" 
        # Rename the file
        Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName "$new_name"

        $new_file_name = $file.fullname
        & $Path\UIni.exe $new_file_name AGM CRM AGM_CUR_CRM AGM_CUR_CRM.CMD 
                   #this how I read the .ini file
        start-sleep -s 1

        $Read_AGM_CUR_CRM = Get-Content .\AGM_CUR_CRM.CMD
        $a_AGM_CUR_CRM,$b_AGM_CUR_CRM     = $Read_AGM_CUR_CRM -split "="
        $b_AGM_CUR_CRM 
    }


}
}

$A = Pick_file
```

Comment: See also Theo's answer, which actually gives you a handle on how to solve your problem.  The key is to use $renamedfile.FullName as the handle on the file you pass to UInin.exe.